# Replace text before a specific word in Geany?

Tags: geany

I'm struggling here a bit with a JSON file where I need to delete every ID in the file. Is there any faster way than doing it manually. I need to delete numbers before the name value :

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [cut](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cut_(Unix)) command in the terminal and write the output to another file which can be used. This will preserve your original file as is.

In your case specifically I see that the ID is 20 characters long, counting the characters till `name` it comes out to be 28.

Go to the terminal and use the following command in the directory where your `json` file is located :
`cut -c29- filename.json > newfilename.json`

This will remove first 28 characters from each line in the file, which should leave you with the desired result. For clarity, `-c29-` is not a mistake - the 29th character is excluded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and don't forget to do a backup of your file, in case that you do a mistake